# creating and storing gestures in android

Tags: android, gestures

I am building an app in android in which I am supposed to let the user create `gesture` and store info against them, so later he can retrieve that information by drawing that `gesture`. Now i want to know that how to make and store gestures programmaticaly. Any code snippet would be helpful. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample application that demonstrates creating, storing and reloading of gestures. Search in your Android SDK install folder for samples/android-11/GestureBuilder.

Comment: thanks , exactly what i needed , now  i just want to ask that i am going to save every gestures with a description each , so how should i do that? should i use a database or what?

Comment: You'll probably want to use a database and tie each gesture definition to a row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html